# my magento 1.9.1 not sending newsletter emails and order email to customers

Tags: magento-1.9, customer, sales, newsletter, order-email

my magento is not sending any order or newsletter email: exception log giving following errors:

```
2016-03-05T10:44:35+00:00 ERR (3): 
exception 'Zend_Mail_Protocol_Exception' with message 'Incorrect authentication data
' in /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract.php:431
Stack trace:
#0 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login.php(95): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Abstract->_expect(235)
#1 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp.php(217): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp_Auth_Login->auth()
#2 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp.php(200): Zend_Mail_Protocol_Smtp->helo('localhost')
#3 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract.php(348): Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp->_sendMail()
#4 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Zend_Mail.php(1194): Zend_Mail_Transport_Abstract->send(Object(Zend_Mail))
#5 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template.php(132): Zend_Mail->send(Object(Zend_Mail_Transport_Smtp))
#6 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template.php(508): Aschroder_SMTPPro_Model_Email_Template->send(Array, Array, Array)
#7 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer.php(42): Mage_Core_Model_Email_Template->sendTransactional('3', 'sales', Array, Array, Array, '1')
#8 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php(1354): Fooman_EmailAttachments_Model_Core_Email_Template_Mailer->send()
#9 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/Mage_Sales_Model_Order.php(1369): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->queueNewOrderEmail(true)
#10 /home/sirajand/public_html/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Sales/OrderController.php(139): Mage_Sales_Model_Order->sendNewOrderEmail()
#11 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(14098): Mage_Adminhtml_Sales_OrderController->emailAction()
#12 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18515): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('email')
#13 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(18045): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#14 /home/sirajand/public_html/includes/src/__default.php(20862): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#15 /home/sirajand/public_html/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#16 /home/sirajand/public_html/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#17 {main}
2016-03-05T10:45:47+00:00 ERR (3):
```

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you are using Aschroder_SMTPPro and your Credentials for your SMTP Mailer are incorrect.